# just dial url in not opening in vba get request

Tags: vba

```
url = https://www.justdial.com/Bangalore/Internet-Website-Developers/nct-11035713/page-1

Function getPageContent(ByVal url As String) As String
        Set objHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
        objHTTP.Open "GET", url, False
        objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
        objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Cache-Control", "no-cache"
        objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Pragma", "no-cache"
        objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.135 Safari/537.36"
        objHTTP.send
        If objHTTP.Status = 200 Then
            getPageContent = objHTTP.responseText
        End If
    End Function
```

I am trying to extract justdial webpage but I am not getting the response, Instead i am getting 504 time out error. see my code for any corrections. I am getting response on postman

Comment: What is it you wanna parse from that page @Sunil Kumar?

Comment: wanted to scrape some listings

Comment: Try using `CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")` instead of `CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")`. I found it working using the earlier. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please, adapt the function in this way (it needs `MSXML2.XMLHTTP60`). **It needs a reference to 'Microsoft XML, v6.0'** - (In VBE - Tools - References, scroll down, check it when found and press 'OK') :

```
Function getPageContent(ByVal url As String) As String
 'It needs reference to 'Microsoft XML, v6.0'
 Dim objHTTP As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
 With objHTTP
    .Open "GET", url, False
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
    .setRequestHeader "Cache-Control", "no-cache"
    .setRequestHeader "Pragma", "no-cache"
    .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.135 Safari/537.36"
    .send
    If .status = 200 Then
        getPageContent = .responseText
    End If
  End With
End Function
```

Tested it in the next way:

```
Sub testExtractPage()
 Dim url As String
 url = "https://www.justdial.com/Bangalore/Internet-Website-Developers/nct-11035713/page-1"
 Debug.Print getPageContent(url)'See the result in Immediate Window (Ctrl + G, in VBE)
End Sub
```

Comment: @Sunil Kumar: Didn't my above code answer your question? Did you find some time to check it?

Comment: @Sunil Kumar: Did you create the requested reference? Do you receive an error? How do you call the function? It worked very well on my computer. I will show you how I checked it...

Comment: @Sunil Kumar: Don't you have any feedback? Did you add the suggested reference? Should I better explain how to do it? Since, it works on my computer, it is not possible to not work on yours...

Comment: I added a reference and i did not receive any error it was only time out and result was comming empty  I call it like normally only var = getPageContent(url)

Comment: @Sunil Kumar: Please, put this code line in the function, just after `.send`: `Debug.Print .status`. What does it return in Immediate Window? How did you check that `var` does not contain the string? How was `var` been declared?

Comment: @Sunil Kumar: Please, put this code line in the function, just after `.send`: `Debug.Print .status`. What does it return in Immediate Window? Isn't it 200? How did you check has `var` does not contain the string? How was `var` been declared?

Comment: Debug.Print .status is printing 504 for me

Comment: @Sunil Kumar:  This cannot be true... Do you use my above function exactly **as it is**?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220502/discussion-between-sunil-kumar-and-faneduru).